# Where can I find information for how to create amateur radio telescope?

Tags: home-experiment, telescopes, radio

Where can I find good source of information for how to create amateur radio telescope.
Particularly interested in creating Fresnel Zone Plate Antennas (aka flat dish).

- design, diagrams, electronics.
- discussions about probes in production etc.

Comment: Ever heard of Google? I just tried "amateur radio astronomy", and believe it or not, at least a dozen of pages popped up. There is a society!

Comment: Believe it or not every question have answer somewhere on the Internet indexed by Google, what is you point here? SE sites are for questions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a step back, what do you want to study with your telescope? The telescope is just one component in your DIY astronomy lab. You are also going to need a plan for your study, a way to acquire signals from your telescope, and a way to process those signals.

Some telescope / antenna stuff -

- A guy who built a telescope for [examining Hydrogen emissions](http://www.signalone.com/radioastronomy/telescope/)
- Some thoughts on designing [Fresnel Antennas](http://www.setileague.org/articles/fresnel.htm)